# Git - Attempting to clone from remote repository - Permission denied, incorrect password error

Tags: git, github, ssh, version-control, https

I am no git expert, but as I understand it, I should be able to clone a repository from a remote network.

I have setup a repo on Computer A. I have done `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit`

I believe this sets up the repository on my computer.

I then used 'whatsmyip' to find out the IP of this computer.

I attempted to clone this repo onto Computer B, by doing the following:

('mkdir etc')

```
'git clone ssh://my_username@the_ip_of_the_computer:/home/my_username/repo_directory'
```

I also tried variants of this, such as https rather than ssh.

Perhaps I am just attempting something which doesn't make complete sense because I haven't understood git properly? I am essentially using it to sync files between computers without having to use (pay for) github.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Oops, I didn't point out what was going wrong: The terminal prints 'Permission denied, please try again.' - But I guess you probably already assumed that from the title of this post.

Comment: Before trying to clone, can you verify that `ssh my_username@the_ip_of_the_computer` works? You might need to run `ssh-server` on your machine A in order to make this work using `sudo service ssh status` and `sudo service ssh start`.

Comment: @mu無 I get 'ssh unrecognized service'

Comment: Okay I've installed openssh-server, now I can connect to localhost

Comment: so now check if the clone works using `git clone my_username@the_ip_of_the_computer:/home/my_username/repo_directory`. My guess is it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a password in your git command like this:

```
git clone https://my_username:my_password@the_ip_of_the_computer/home/my_username/repo_directory.git
```

Or setting up SSH keys between the two computers so that you don't need to provide a password.

One way you can check whether you have the IP, user, and password correct is by trying an SSH to that machine like this:

```
ssh my_username@the_ip_of_the_computer
```

Comment: Ah, seems SSH isn't working? Tried the first command: 'ssh: Could not resolve hostname <username>: Name or service not known' - then the secon ssh command: 'Please enter password: <password> \n Permission Denied'

Comment: Maybe it would help if I apt-get ssh on the other computer?

Comment: Nope, that did not help... Still incorrect password error

Comment: Ok, edited the first command in my answer, you can try that. But the second thing sounds like you are not using the correct password. You should be using the username and password for your remote machine that is hosting the repository.

Comment: Yeah I am doing that, let me try again

Comment: The updated method above with https appears to be working, but I now get a certificate error? 'server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none' - so I don't have a certificate? What should I do to proceed?

Comment: Oh, that's because of the "https", try it with "http" instead, does that work?

Comment: No, same error unfortunately. Should I be using the SSH or HTTP method? I'm not sure I fully understand the difference, except HTTPS is recommended on the github website...

Comment: Did you get the certificate error again with `git clone http://my_username:my_password@the_ip_of_the_computer/home/my_username/repo_directory.git` ? It shouldn't be checking the certificate if it's not https.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, the director is: /home/username/gittest

Comment: Sorry to say it, but those errors don't make sense as far as I can tell, you are probably best off using SSH keys. See here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server